# accessibility does not read some text in flutter how to fix that?

Tags: flutter

In my new flutter app faild on accessibility test. Some text such as hint text and some other text does not recogonize the accessibility. How to fix that ?
There is 6 tiles in my home screem every tile contain logo and Text. Text contain both english and thai. Some text are read by Accessibility, some text speech english only. I need to read both English and Thai ?.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the question.

Comment: code are long, so i didnt pase here

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextSpan.locale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan/locale.html) to specify which voice that the screen reader should use.

```
const Text.rich(
  TextSpan(children: [
    TextSpan(text: 'UK text. ', locale: Locale('en', 'UK')),
    TextSpan(text: 'American text. ', locale: Locale('en', 'US')),
    TextSpan(text: 'Dansk text. ', locale: Locale('da', 'DK')),
  ]),
),
```

Unfortunately this seem to be the only way we can currently affect which voice that assistive technology should use in Flutter.

On Flutter web and windows, TextSpan.locale is currently not working. ([issue#98949](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98948))